# React, RN, Is inline styling on the compoent really bad?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I don't know much about styling, but our team member insists that #2-method is much harder to do in #1-method.

Is the #1 way really bad so that I should try to make him switch?

## 1

```
render() {
    return (
         <p style={{color: 'red'}}>
            Example Text
        </p>
    );
}
```

## 2

```
render() {
  const styles = {
    color: 'blue'
  }

  return (
      <p style={styles}>
        Example Text
      </p>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both of them works for sure but there is a catch with inline styling.

React Native's `StyleSheet.create({})` caches styles so app needs to send lesser data over the bridge.
If you declare the styles as inline then over every render your styles are sent over the bridge to draw which lessens the performance.

When you declare styles using `StyleSheet.create` only subsequent renders styles are referenced by some quick key like mechanism which gives better performance.

So yes try to use the `StyleSheet.create` as much as possible

Here is some more info regarding StyleSheet and styling in React Native [Medium Link](https://medium.com/mindorks/everything-to-know-about-styling-in-react-native-7e30aed53ad)

Answer (score 3):

Both of them are ok and you can create your app with both of them, #1 is fine for small projects but in big/complex projects  #1 will be messy and you want separate your styling from your codes and you want to be more organized.

In RN you should use #2  to manage your codes easier and have better readability, and in `react js` project, you should have a separate external CSS file like stylesheet.css and use it in your project (like regular,`HTML CSS`),
Personally, I just use #1 when I am testing something.

Hope this be useful for you.